# Setting multiple scalar variables in one SELECT with clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that resembles the following format:

```
select 
    @minValue = min(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @maxValue = max(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @avgValue = avg(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @userValue = (select value where id = '12345') -- <--Can this be done?
from 
    (select
         id, value
     from 
         complexInnerQuery) outerQuery
```

I'm trying to set min, max, avg values from my subquery while also trying to get a particular value based on the id I pass in. Is this doable in a single query? My objective was to avoid calling another function to get that output for the sake of performance.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks reasonable to me.  Have you tried it?

Comment: the line containing `--<--` seems to be missing the from clause, or you need to move the where to after the outerquery.  the ()'s are also off imo.

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way; it should give you an error since the id and value needs to by in a group by clause.

Comment: @jpw That's what I was getting so I tried adding the group by clause to the outerQuery and ran it. The engine ran the SQL but didn't return anything.. which makes sense since I haven't fetched it from anything. If I reference outerQuery in my select, then it tells me that the object doesn't exist.

Comment: @RizJa I would guess that you maybe could rewrite it using common table expressions, but without knowing more about your actual query etc its hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% how you intend to pass in the id, but I'd go with the suggestion by @jpw and use a cte for the outer query:

```
with outerQuery
as (
    select id
        ,value
    from complexInnerQuery
    )
select @minValue = min(outerQuery.Consumption)
    ,@maxValue = max(outerQuery.Consumption)
    ,@avgValue = avg(outerQuery.Consumption)
    ,@userValue = (
        select value
        from outerQuery
        where id = '12345'
        ) 
from outerQuery
```

Alternately, adding a from clause to your subquery for @userValue might get you where you need to be:

```
select 
    @minValue = min(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @maxValue = max(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @avgValue = avg(outerQuery.Consumption),
    @userValue = (select value from outerQuery where id = '12345') -- <--Can this be done?
     from 
     (
         select
            id,
            value
         from 
            complexInnerQuery
    ) outerQuery
```

If that's not helpful, post a little more info about the inner query and what you are doing regarding the @userValue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was avoiding CTEs since they were degrading the query performance in my case. As for the second approach, I can verify it doesn't work. Using outerQuery to derive userValue results in "Invalid object name". That being said, the CTE does work and it doesn't look like there's syntactically another way to go about it given what I was trying to do. Marking this as the answer. :)

Comment: @RizJa If you think the cte is degrading the query, try replacing the cte in agileMikes first code block with a temp table. eg. `select id,value into #tmptable from complexInnerQuery`.

Comment: If you do put the data set into a temp table as g2server suggests it seems like you could then use that in your from clause for your subquery that sets @userValue as well your main query and avoid the cte altogether.